# Configure Zip/Copy Task in a Plugin with Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to create an `Zip` task in a plugin:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        Zip buildFunctionArchive = project.tasks.create("buildFunctionArchive", Zip.class) {

            archiveClassifier = "yolo"
            from(project.getTasksByName("compileJava", true))
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason even though the `compileJava` task exists in the project form which I use my plugin. When I print debug output I get: `NO-SOURCE`

```
2020-10-05T02:16:03.565+1100 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :buildFunctionArchive NO-SOURCE
```

If I configure the `from` in my client project:

```
buildFunctionArchive{
    from compileJava
}
```

This works, and I even see the `yolo` in the archive name. But if I remove the `from compileJava`

```
buildFunctionArchive{
}
```

As well as removing the configuration all together and running `gradle buildFunctionArchive`
The task will not create the archive, even though I have configured this in the `MyPlugin` class, I will get the `NO-SOURCE` error. What am I missing? I am wanting to define a `Zip` task in my plugin but am having no luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar problem...